# Multi-Column join: Getting additional rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, join

Table1:

```
timezone         some_data       joincol2

America/Denver   22/04/16 7:23   abd
America/Chicago  22/04/16 7:23   abc
America/Adak     22/04/16 7:23   abc
America/Adak     22/04/16 7:23   abe
```

This is a fact table with data coming in from source.

Table2:

```
timezone         Value_needed      joincol2

America/Chicago    0               NULL
America/Adak      -5               NULL
America/Adak      -4               abc
America/Denver    -2               NULL
```

This is a static table.

DEsired result: Joining these tables on `timezone` and `joincol2` and get `value_needed` column from table 2, in a way, when joincol2 matches then the corresponding value else the value which is against null for the timezone.

Query I wrote:

```
SELECT table1.timezone, 
       table1.joincol2 AS left_joincol2, 
       table2.joincol2 AS right_joincol2, 
       value_needed 
FROM   table1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 
              ON ( table1.joincol2 = table2.joincol2 
                    OR table2.joincol2 IS NULL ) 
                 AND table2.timezone = table1.timezone
```

Result I got:

```
timezone        left_joincol2   right_joincol2  value   some_data

America/Denver  abd                             -2      22/04/16 7:23
America/Chicago abc                              0      22/04/16 7:23
America/Adak    abc                             -5      22/04/16 7:23 --Bad Row
America/Adak    abc             abc             -4      22/04/16 7:23
America/Adak    abe                             -5      22/04/16 7:23
```

I want to remove this Bad row (3rd row) in the result above. I think I can't apply rank/ partition function to achieve this as there will be a lot of data, which can allowed to be duplicate in table 1 (or can I?).

Can you please help me reach to the solution? Result I want (ideally should be equal number of rows as table1):

```
timezone        left_joincol2   right_joincol2  value   some_data

America/Denver  abd                             -2      22/04/16 7:23
America/Chicago abc                              0      22/04/16 7:23
America/Adak    abc             abc             -4      22/04/16 7:23
America/Adak    abe                             -5      22/04/16 7:23
```

P.S. I have full control on system. Can add primary keys or anything you suggest.
Feel free to ask in case I missed on some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could treat the static table as two tables, one joined on "joincol2" and one where joincol2 is null. Then coalesce the two values together, with the desired value first so it wins when present. Something like:

```
select t1.*, 
coalesce(t2.value_needed, t2_default.value_needed) as value_needed
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 
  on t1.timezone = t2.timezone 
  and t1.joincol2 = t2.joincol2
left join table2 t2_default 
  on t1.timezone = t2_default.timezone 
  and t2_default.joincol2 is null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for. To sound more foolish, I was thinking to create two tables out of t2 and join them. Thanks a lot man. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT timezone, left_joincol2, right_joincol2, value_needed
FROM (
  SELECT table1.timezone, 
         table1.joincol2 AS left_joincol2, 
         table2.joincol2 AS right_joincol2, 
         value_needed,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table1.timezone, table1.joincol2
                            ORDER BY CASE 
                                        WHEN table2.joincol2=table1.joincol2 THEN 1 
                                        ELSE 2 
                                     END) AS rn
  FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.timezone = table1.timezone ) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The query use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to selectively pick the *correct* right record within each `table1.timezone, table1.joincol2` partition.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c7052/4)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wrote the same thing, but will this work if there are multiple rows with same joincol2 and multiple rows with joincol2 as null. Also, any thing we can do to improve performance on this window function?

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra Can you add some sample data to explain the case? Using indices is the way to go with window function.

Comment: -betsos Thank you very much, for the help. I got the solution. Cheers.